# Views Tipadas em ASP.NET MVC, usando ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de saber se toda View em Mvc tem que ser tipada?

Quero pegar valores de um formulário mas que esses valores não sejam de uma mesma entidade. Estou usando um helper:

```
@Html.TexBoxFor(model => model.Nome)
```

Gostaria de saber como faço pegar o valor deste helper sem ter que usar `model => model.Nome` sendo que `nome` é uma propriedade de uma entidade. Quando não tipo minha View não pegar o valor das textbox.

Comment: Onde estão esses outros valores que você precisa pegar?

Comment: Quero fazer o seguinte. Criar um formulário que irá inserir informações em  mais de um tabela no evento click do botão salve. Mas quando tipo a View só consigo usar as propriedades daquela entidade que ela foi tipada. Espero ter sido claro.

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso, você precisa criar um *ViewModel*. Um *ViewModel* é idêntico a um *Model*, mas não guarda informações em um banco.

Coloque dentro dele todas as propriedades dos vários *Models* que serão salvos. Ao enviar para o *Controller*, você terá que criar os *Models* manualmente e inserir neles as informações vindas no `ViewModel`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MinhaAction(MeuViewModel viewModel) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        var model1 = new MeuModel1();
        model1.Prop1 = viewModel.Prop1;
        model1.Prop2 = viewModel.Prop2;
        ...
        context.MeuModel1.Add(model1);
        context.SaveChanges();

        var model2 = new MeuModel2();
        model2.Prop1 = viewModel.Prop3;
        model2.Prop2 = viewModel.Prop4;
        ...
        context.MeuModel2.Add(model2);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("OutraAction"); 
    }

    // Caso o ViewModel não seja válido, cai aqui.
    return View(viewModel);
}
```